# Ruby : How to create an array of integers [0, 10..31]

Tags: ruby

I need to create an array of integers.

The array contains the number 0, and then number 10 to 31.

I understand that I can type it in, but I really wish there is an eloquent Ruby way to do it.

Comment: A small thing: you should write the array you want as `[0, 10,..., 31]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this:

```
[0, *10..31]
```

Comment: Splats FTW.  As Ruby 1.8 is now [officially retired](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/) this is the perfect answer.

Comment: splatter, splatter, splatter, on the windshield of life

Answer (score 1):

@xdazz answer is better than this but if you aren't comfortable using the splat operator here is an alternate(less pretty) approach:

```
[0, (10..31).to_a].flatten
```

Comment: or `(0..31).to_a - (1..9).to_a`, but @xdazz nailed it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland or even `[*0..31] - [*1..9]`:)

Comment: and suppose you were limited to using the digits zero and one?  (It's late.)